# In ng-repeat list is not getting updated

Tags: html, angularjs, controller

Here is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/krthk2005/j5ze42bf/10/

Question Update: I was unable to update the class and style please let me know

I am trying to populate the list using ng-repeat and when I update the values in the list it needs to be updated.

HTML CODE:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
    <button ng-click="updatedList(stickyList)">Updated List</button>
  <div id="mainStickyLayout" ng-repeat="sticky in stickyList">
    <!-- Stickies can be defined using ordinary HTML. Just put the "sticky" class on a wrapper around a textarea! -->
    <div id="sticky{{$index}}" class="sticky {{sticky.color}}" style="{{sticky.style}}">
      <textarea ng-model="sticky.content"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
  {{finalList}}
  </p>
</div>
```

JS CODE

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
function Ctrl1($scope) {
     $scope.stickyList = [{
    "content": "store",
    "style": "top: 100px; left: 140px;",
    "color": "sticky-orange"
  }, {
    "content": "your",
    "style": "top: 200px; left: 240px;",
    "color": "sticky-blue"
  }, {
    "content": "note",
    "style": "top: 300px; left: 340px;",
    "color": "sticky-yellow"
  }, {
    "content": "here",
    "style": "top: 400px; left: 440px;",
    "color": "sticky-green"
  }];
  $scope.updatedList = function(stickyList) {
        $scope.finalList = stickyList;
    }
}
```

I wrote the update functionality using angularjs

Please check the image that I posted. I need to have 4 textareas with different stylings and classes and it needs to be updated dynamically

[image: I need to update the style parameters]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the text area.  You need to have it like this to have 2 way binding instead of one way:

```
<textarea ng-model="sticky.content"></textarea>
```

Comment: I need to update the style also then how I can do it

Comment: you need to use ng-class and ng-style on the div instead of class and style

Comment: I was unable to update the class and style.. could you please suggest

Answer (score 0):

To do the other fields do something like this. As you can see, you are binding the textareas to specific keys on the ng-repeated objects.

```
<textarea ng-model="sticky.content">{{sticky.content}}</textarea>
<textarea ng-model="sticky.class">{{sticky.class}}</textarea>
<textarea ng-model="sticky.style">{{sticky.style}}</textarea>
```

Comment: I was unable to update the class and style.. could you please suggest

Comment: I need to update the `style` i.e. `CSS` and `class` of the `element`. Not the **value**

Comment: Everything you are asking can be found within the angular2 documentation at the following url:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html

Comment: I am using angular 1.5 not angular 2.0 version

Comment: Then use this link .  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass.  It will show you how to dynamically add a class based on user input.  Should be everything you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the binding you have on text area is one way. Your changes are not being reflected back to the backend value. Change it to a two way binding and it should work

```
<textarea>{{sticky.content}}</textarea> //one way binding

<textarea ng-model= "sticky.content"></textarea> //two way binding(correct)
```

Comment: I was unable to update the class and style.. could you please suggest

Comment: You have only one text area and that is bound to sticky.content. You need another textarea(or similar input element) where you can edit you style/color.

Eg: 
<textarea ng-model= "sticky.content"></textarea>
<textarea ng-model= "sticky.style"></textarea> 
<textarea ng-model= "sticky.color"></textarea>

Comment: I need to update the style i.e. CSS and class of the element. Not the value

Comment: Please check the image that I posted. I need to have 4 textareas with different stylings and classes and it needs to be updated dynamically

Comment: Where are you updating your sticky.style and sticky.color values?